# Como detectar se o PHP está rodando em linha de comando ou servidor?

Tags: php

As vezes, quando rodo algum script PHP, tenho a necessidade de saber se ele está rodando na linha de comando ou não, pois caso esteja rodando na linha de comando, posso executar uma ação diferente.

Existe alguma maneira de detectar se o script está rodando na linha de comando ou se ele está rodando em um servidor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a função [**`php_sapi_name()`**](http://php.net/php_sapi_name), se o retorno for `"cli"`, está executando na linha de comando.

A documentação do PHP diz:

> ```php
> string php_sapi_name(void)
> ```
>
> Retorna uma string minúscula que descreve o tipo de interface entre o servidor web e o PHP (Server API, SAPI). Em CGI PHP, esta string é "cgi", em mod_php para o Apache, esta string é "apache" e assim por diante.

Exemplo:

```php
if (php_sapi_name() == "cli") {
    // Executando na linha de comando
} else {
    // Executando no servidor 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

É possível fazer isso verificando o valor da constante `PHP_SAPI`.

Se for `"cli"`, está rodando na linha de comando.

Exemplo:

```
if (PHP_SAPI === 'cli') {
     // Está na linha de comando
} else {
    // Está rodando no via servidor 
}
```

**Nota**: Quando o script estiver rodando em um servidor, os valores retornados pela constante `PHP_SAPI` ou a função `php_sapi_name` podem variar de acordo com o servidor. Por exemplo, ao rodar no Apache2, o valor retornado será `"apache2handler"`, se usar o *built-in server* do PHP, o valor retornado é `"cli-server"`. Mas o valor retornado ao usar na linha de comando é sempre `"cli"`.